# Prove this function is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function 
$$f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \\ f(z)= 2z + 3\bar{z} .$$

Using the limit definition, by finding an inequality between $|f(z) - f(a)|$ and $|z - a|$, show that $f$ is continuous at every point in $\mathbb{C}$.

Could anyone please explain how I can approach this please?

Comment: Expand and bound $|f(z)-f(a)|$. Note that if you learnt the addition rule, it suffices to show continuity of $\bar z$, which is quasi-immediate.

Comment: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. For $|z-a|<\delta(\varepsilon)$ we have $|f(z)-f(a)|=\ldots=5|z-a|$ and now it's your turn.

Comment: Hint: use the triangle inequality and the fact that $|\overline{w}| = \overline{|w|} = |w|$.

Answer (score 2):

The requested inequality derives from the triangular inequality

$$|f(z)-f(a)|=|2z+3\bar z-2a-3\bar a|\le2|z-a|+3|\bar z-\bar a|=5|z-a|.$$

Comment: A few steps are missing, your task.

Comment: Yeap, thanks! It clears it up a lot.